# r - How to create multiple new columns when conditions met in original columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm pretty fresh to r (like 2 days old). I have a set of data that is a time series taken every 200 msecs over a few hours. Here's the

```
head(dat):

Date    Time    MSec Sample Pat1  Pat2  Pat3    
1 8/7/~ 14:34   411      0    100   13    13    
2 8/7/~ 14:34   615      1    13    13    143    
3 8/7/~ 14:34   814      2    13    13    13    
4 8/7/~ 14:34    12      3    130   13    13    
5 8/7/~ 14:34   216      4    13    13    130    
6 8/7/~ 14:34   417      5    139   13    13
```

It goes down for 2 hours, so several thousands points and over for several hundred patients. The 13 is our baseline and what we are interested in spikes in activity over say 100. I have been trying to create a new column for each Patient column for every time a signal is over 100. I've worked out the follow code:

```
dat$Pat1exc <- as.numeric(dat$Pat1 >=100)
```

This works and gives me the new column and my data looks like below:

```
Date    Time    MSec Sample Pat1  Pat2  Pat3  Pat1exc   
1 8/7/~ 14:34   411      0    100   13    13    1
2 8/7/~ 14:34   615      1    13    13    143   0 
3 8/7/~ 14:34   814      2    13    13    13    0
4 8/7/~ 14:34    12      3    130   13    13    1
5 8/7/~ 14:34   216      4    13    13    130   0 
6 8/7/~ 14:34   417      5    139   13    13    1
```

This is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to iterate through each column to create Pat2exc, Pat3exc, etc. I figured I could use sapply or vapply after I create a function. However, I can't get the function to work.

```
excite <- function(x, y) {y <- as.numeric(x >=100)}
excite(x=dat$Pat2, y=dat$Pat2exc)
```

This gives me no errors, but doesn't modify the `dat` data frame. Essentially, in the end I just want to sum up all the excited columns (>=100). If there is an easier way to count the samples over 100 for each patient then I'd be happy to learn how to do that as well.

Sorry if this is unclear. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am also looking for a good way to combine the Time and Msec columns.

Edit: Added in unabbreviated data:

```
 Date       Time        Msecs
 8/7/2018   14:34:07    411
 8/7/2018   14:34:07    615
 8/7/2018   14:34:07    814
 8/7/2018   14:34:08    12
 8/7/2018   14:34:08    216
 8/7/2018   14:34:08    417
 8/7/2018   14:34:08    619
 8/7/2018   14:34:08    816
 8/7/2018   14:34:09    15
```

Comment: How would you want `Time` and `Msec` to be combined? What does `Msec` stand for?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's milliseconds. The `Time` column got abbreviated, but it should be 14:34:02 or `%H%:%M%:%S%`. Ideally, the two could be combined into `14:34:02.411,` but still be readable as a time rather than a string.

Comment: If that's the case, would you provide a non-abbreviated version of `Time`? or do you not care about the seconds as long as it is combined with `Msec`? (i.e. I can just attach 00 seconds to `Time`)

Comment: Okay, I put the non-abbreviated data in my edit. Basically, my data gives me the date, time with hours, minutes and seconds, and in another column I get millisecs for each point. I have been using only `Time` to analyze this, but I think R can understand milliseconds as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr` to create the binary variables and `mutate` + `rowSums` to add them all up:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Pat")), funs(exc = (. >= 100)*1)) %>%
  mutate(exc_total = rowSums(.[grepl('_exc', names(.))]))
```

**Result:**

```
   Date  Time MSec Sample Pat1 Pat2 Pat3 Pat1_exc Pat2_exc Pat3_exc exc_total
1 8/7/~ 14:34  411      0  100   13   13        1        0        0         1
2 8/7/~ 14:34  615      1   13   13  143        0        0        1         1
3 8/7/~ 14:34  814      2   13   13   13        0        0        0         0
4 8/7/~ 14:34   12      3  130   13   13        1        0        0         1
5 8/7/~ 14:34  216      4   13   13  130        0        0        1         1
6 8/7/~ 14:34  417      5  139   13   13        1        0        0         1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked really well, the only thing I had to do was sum up the columns. I wasn't clear that I wanted to total the binary values of _each column_ rather than each row. I wouldn't need that in the graph anyway!